# Is there an utility to control the LCD brightness of an MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac

Seriously, the brightness control of my MacBook Pro is really bad. I use it often at night in a dark room, but the lowest brightness setting is still so bright that the whole room is enlighted. It burns in the eyes. One step more less brightness is completely dark.

Is there an utility that allows a better, fine control over the brightness?

Comment: What OS version are you using? 10.6.3 fixed this problem for a lot of people on the LED backlit MBPs.

Comment: I'm running 10.6.3. I see no fix. Still the same idiotically bad brightness control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love using [Nocturne](http://docs.blacktree.com/nocturne/nocturne) (from Blacktree, the same people who make Quicksilver) at night in pitch-black rooms. It eases eye strain so much; it's amazing.

Comment: that's pretty cool!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who much this will really help but you can get finer brightness control by pressing ALT + SHIFT + BRIGHTNESSKEY (meaning the F1/F2 on most newer Macs). Works well for the volume keys also.

-Mike

Comment: good, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the "way too bright" problem in dark rooms.

Comment: *4 years* owning this mac and I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [f.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/). Free. Adjusts the monitor based on time of day. Works *wonderfully* when doing the late night work.